# how can run curl in tcl and sort to output

Tags: curl, tcl

I have a little problem here and hope someone can help me, i want to do a curl query with this script

```
bind pub -|- !ttest proc:ttest
proc proc:ttest {nick host handle channel arg} {
    set name test1
    set ftp homeftp
    if {[catch {
        exec /usr/bin/curl -u :pass -X POST https://localhost:55477/raw -d '{"command": "site search $name", "sites": ["$ftp"]}' --insecure
    } error]} {
        putnow "PRIVMSG #test :$error"
    }
}
```

when i run it in bash the output looks like this:

```
root@test /eggdrop $ /usr/bin/curl -u :pass -X POST https://localhost:55477/raw -d '{"command": "site search test1", "sites": ["homeftp"]}' --insecure
{
"failures": [],
"successes": [
{
  "name": "homeftp",
  "result": "200- Found 50 entries in index (limit 50):\r\n200- /home/test/test1\r\n200-/home/test/test1/test1\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test11\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test13\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test13\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- /home/test/test1/test14\r\n200- Search complete\r\n"
}
]
}
root@test
```

In the end it should look like this

```
output in channel
<testbot3> /home/test/test1
<testbot3> /home/test/test1/test1
<testbot3> /home/test/test1/test11
<testbot3> /home/test/test1/test13
<testbot3> /home/test/test1/test14
...
...
simply all among themselves until the end
```

unfortunately I don't know how to go about it and i have erros:

```
<testbot3> extra characters after close-quote
```

Comment: I changed your code a little to add conventional Tcl indentation; it doesn't affect the behaviour, but it makes it a lot easier to read…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in this command:

```
exec /usr/bin/curl -u :pass -X POST https://localhost:55477/raw -d '{"command": "site search $name", "sites": ["$ftp"]}' --insecure
```

The issue is that you've copied some code from somewhere that was intended for shell scripting, and Tcl doesn't treat `'` the same way. (It's in fact a totally unspecial character in Tcl.) Instead, you need to compose the JSON slightly differently:

```
exec /usr/bin/curl -u :pass -X POST https://localhost:55477/raw -d "{\"command\": \"site search $name\", \"sites\": \[\"$ftp\"\]}" --insecure
```

That's not too clear to read. Here, let's break it up a bit more:

```
# These can be set outside the [catch]
set Url https://localhost:55477/raw
set Json "{\"command\": \"site search $name\", \"sites\": \[\"$ftp\"\]}"

exec /usr/bin/curl -u :pass -X POST $Url -d $Json --insecure
```

There are a few Tcl libraries that could be used for building that JSON query (and you probably ought to take care that the parameters you insert into it don't contain “bad” characters like `"`) but it's more important for parsing the JSON result. A simple parser library is in Tcllib; it's documented [here](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-18/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/json/json.html). To do that, assuming you've installed Tcllib, you then add to the top of your script:

```
package require json
```

Then you can parse the results and write them to the channel with something like:

```
set results [exec /usr/bin/curl -u :pass -X POST $Url -d $Json --insecure]

foreach info [dict get [json::json2dict $results] successes] {
    foreach line [split [dict get $info result] "\n"] {
        if {[string match "200-*" $line]} {
            set line [string trim [string range $line 4 end]]
            putnow "PRIVMSG #test :$line"
        }
    }
}
```

You might need a little more work to just get the lines you want.

Comment: Donal Fellows, great that works flawlessly. I had to add to curl -s so it wouldn't show up in the partyline. Thank you very much